# Random ETIMEDOUT error operating with MySQL on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a local application written on NodeJS that operates with a MySQL database hosted on AWS. The application has been running for a few months already without any issue. Lately and apparently randomly, I get:

```
(node:86784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XX.XX.XX:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
```

In the stacktrace I see:

```
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
at Connection._implyConnect (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:454:10)
at Connection.query (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:196:8)
at internal/util.js:297:30
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Connection.subQuery (internal/util.js:296:12)
at _callee3$ (/Users/x/y/z/f/src/persistence/logic.js:84:13)
at tryCatch (/Users/x/y/z/f/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
```

At the end of the stack trace one can see the logic.js file that originated the error.

I have tried to find other posts referencing the same error, but I fail to see the connection with my personal situation. I get the timeout in several places, but this code could be one example:

```
export const doThing = async (x, y, z) => {
  const connection = getConnection();

  const query = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);

  const info = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    z: z,
    started_at: new Date()
  }

  const sql = SQL`INSERT INTO table SET ?`;

  try {
    await query(sql, info);
  }
  finally {
    connection.end();
  }
}
```

I have been thinking about several options:

- An error in the application layer.
- Configuration problem in the database (lack of index, for example, slow query).
- A security issue with AWS.
- Network problem.

The application has been working for some time, I cannot think of a reason why it would fail right now. Although it is true that the application performs some complex queries, it also fails on trivial insert/update queries. And finally, speaking about security, I do have my IP granted and I can access the instance with Sequel Pro without issues. I have also switched to another network, with no luck.

I don't understand what has changed. I recently updated to macOS Big Sur, but I have not found references to a similar problem.